# Running library with shared object files Django

Tags: python, django

I have a library that is using shared object files
`cagui.so cspb.so cspe.so cspib.so`
and I tried to run this library on my Django server but it didn't work. All files are in `/static/`. Do I need a special location for them?

**UPDATE**

It appears I didn't set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Since I use Heroku the solution was to set it in config:

`heroku config:add LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/myapp/foler_with_lib_files`

Comment: I think we need more information. How did you try to run them?  What was the error when you did?

Comment: It worked locally on my PC. I tried to run the function as I did locally 
 `develop(privateKeyFilePath, privateKeyPassword, response["customerCrypto"], response["cert"])` from view.py that links to library's main python file `def develop(privKeyPath, privKeyPassword, customerCrypto, senderCert):`. The API sent me - `{'error': 'Error load library', 'senderInfo': None, 'signInfo': None}` which from their words means "library can't find *.so files"

Comment: And the .so files are in the /static/ directory?  But the python library is locally installed?  Like in a site-packages/ folder?  Or are they also in the /static/ directory?

Comment: My main python file with *.so files are located at `project/app/` and are also in `/static/` directory. I tried to import from path `from app.main import *` and from static `from staticfiles.main import *" both get the same results. I need to load and unload the library within my main.py with `EULoad()` and `EUUnload()` and these functions use *.so files

Comment: Okay.  Sorry, there are a few too many unknowns here for me.  But hopefully someone smarter can help you out.

Comment: No worries. Your question already helped me to try a different approach, so thank you.